# Find non-common items between 2 GROUP_CONCAT ' ed Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table at my mysql server and it looks like
[image]

FirstColumn and SecondColumn includes info that GROUP_CONCAT was applied.

Please note that "YN19GNG1" is common for both side, "YN19GNG**3**" exist at only FirstColumn and "YN19GNG**2**" exist at only SecondColumn.

Here my question;

How can I compare these two columns and find the uncommon ones like in my explanation above?

Please note that number of GROUP_CONCAT operation applied items may be different for each column ?

Comment: You must parse your concatenated value back to separate values. Then you may compare them.

Comment: How can I do this and find differences